# Test started failing with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, nosuchmethoderror

Started getting this error when trying to run the test that was just running fine. No idea what happened!

```
Step failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.<init>(java.net.URI, java.time.Duration, java.time.Duration, org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter, java.net.Proxy, org.openqa.selenium.Credentials)'
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumClientConfig.<init>(AppiumClientConfig.java:62)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumClientConfig.defaultConfig(AppiumClientConfig.java:79)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.<init>(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:109)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:101)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:113)
```

POM (had to remove unnecessary code):

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 [http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"](http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd%22)
4.0.0

<maven.compiler.source>20</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>20</maven.compiler.target>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

io.appium
java-client
8.5.1
org.junit.jupiter
junit-jupiter
5.10.0
test
io.cucumber
cucumber-core
7.13.0
io.cucumber
cucumber-html
0.2.7
io.github.devopsplugin
cobertura
0.0.2
io.cucumber
cucumber-java
7.13.0
io.cucumber
cucumber-jvm-deps
1.0.6
provided
net.masterthought
cucumber-reporting
5.7.6
org.hamcrest
hamcrest
2.2
test
io.cucumber
gherkin
26.2.0
io.cucumber
cucumber-java
7.13.0
org.seleniumhq.selenium
selenium-java
4.11.0
io.cucumber
cucumber-junit
7.13.0
io.cucumber
cucumber-junit
7.13.0
io.cucumber
cucumber-junit
7.13.0
io.cucumber
cucumber-junit
7.13.0
io.cucumber
cucumber-junit
7.13.0
io.cucumber
cucumber-junit
7.13.0
io.cucumber
cucumber-junit
7.13.0
io.cucumber
cucumber-junit
7.13.0
io.cucumber
cucumber-junit
7.13.0
io.github.bonigarcia
webdrivermanager
5.5.3
org.jetbrains
annotations
RELEASE
compile

Comment: Most likely you have a conflict in your dependencies. Dependency A was compiled against B-v1, but you have B-v2 on your classpath.

Comment: More specifilcally, what Appium and Selenium versions do you have on your classpath?

Answer (score 2):

Signature of constructor of ClientConfig class changed between 4.14.0 and 4.13.0 version. That class is from `selenium-http` dependency, which is transitive dependency from `selenium-remote-driver`, on which appium is dependent on.

In their  file, they set the dependency to the latest in given range -> [*build.gradle*](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/9176e8ead6ae19116713d8eb4fd15958bca4f4ca/build.gradle#L43)

So, without any changes to your dependencies, transitive dependency changed and is crashing your run.

Based on: [*transitive-dependencies-management.md*](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/v8.5.1/docs/transitive-dependencies-management.md)

you can hardcode version to 4.13 which should fix the problem.
Example, in your pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency> <!-- explicitly download correct dependency -->
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>  <!-- exclude what appium is downloading -->
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated the appium java-client dependency to the latest and it fixed the issue for me.

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>8.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```